# Unable to write images from firebase to a pdf using pdfkit and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, pdfkit

Trying to generate pdf using data from firebase but unable to write images to the pdf. The main function is a async function and have await operator for the function, which is used to fetch the image. But facing the following error:

> Error: stream.push() after EOF

Please advice.

I tried to add await for the axios which is used to get the image and even tried to write it inside an async function.Then i tried to write the whole thing outside the main function and call it but the EOF issue is again displayed.

```
//this is the main function //
async function getPDF() {

...
...

//This is the part where I try to write images from firebase ///

await questionNumber.get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
            i++;
           var exteriorQuestionsData = doc.data();
 for(x=0;x<extFormDataAnswers[i-11].exteriorQuestionsImages.length;x++){

if(extFormDataAnswers[i-11].exteriorQuestionsImages!= undefined || extFormDataAnswers[i-11].exteriorQuestionsImages!= [] ) {

              img_url = extFormDataAnswers[i-11].exteriorQuestionsImages[x].uri
              axios.get(img_url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).then(response => {
                var my_img = Buffer.from(response.data);
                pdf_doc.image(my_img,{ fit: [300, 300] })                 
                .fontSize(18)
                .fillColor('#426998')
                .font('Helvetica-Bold')
                .moveDown(0.2)
                .lineWidth(0.5); 
              });   
             }
           }   

            });
          });

....
....
```

The expected result is that the images should be displayed in the pdf but the following error is encountered `Error: stream.push() after EOF`

Comment: Did you try `pdf_doc.end()` after `pdf_doc.image()` ?

Comment: Yes I added pdf_doc.end() at the end of my main function as there are lot of things to be written after getting the image.